# Removing duplicate sub-arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as such: `[[1,3],[2,5],[1,3],[2,5]]`   and i would like to remove any duplicate sub-arrays. I tried using this code:

```
 uniqueArray = array.filter(function(item, pos) {
   return array.indexOf(item) == pos;   });
```

It still returns true for all the cases.

Which function can i use to get the desired result.

Comment: You may want to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Will the arrays always be sorted the same way? Is `[1,3]` a duplicate of `[3,1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most efficient method, but the sub-arrays can be used as object keys:

```js
a = [[1,3],[2,5],[1,3],[2,5]]

o = a.reduce((r, v) => (r[v] = v, r), {})

console.log(JSON.stringify( Object.values(o) ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( o ))
```

**Update**: seems a bit faster with numeric keys :

```js
let a = [[1,3],[2,5],[1,3],[2,5]], t, b, n = _ => performance.now(), 
v = Object.values, l = t => console.log(JSON.stringify(b), t) 

t = n(); b = v(a.reduce((r, v) => (r[v] = v, r), {}))                   ; l(n() - t)

t = n(); b = v(a.reduce((r, v) => (r[v[0] + 1 / v[1]] = v, r), {}))     ; l(n() - t)

t = n(); b = v(a.reduce((r, v) => (r[v[0] + 1 / v[1]] = v, r), new Map)); l(n() - t)
```

Comment: Not sure why you suggest it's not efficient

Comment: @charlietfl because the sub-arrays are converted to strings that are compared, instead of comparing the sub-arrays directly.

Comment: Right but iterating back through to compare each sub array would be expensive

Answer (score 5):

Conver the 2D array into 1D array with stringified elements

Then put then into a `Set` to automatically filter out the repeating elements

Now convert the Set back to an array and map the array by JSON parsing each element to restore back the arrays.

> Readable and no nested loops.

```js
const arr = [[1,3],[2,5],[1,3],[2,5]];

const setArray = new Set(arr.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)))

const uniqArray = [...setArray].map(x => JSON.parse(x))

console.log(uniqArray)
```

Comment: I think this is the most straight forward for me to be honest. Although other ones work aswell

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with an object that will store a hash for each iterated tuple:

```js
var arr = [[1,3],[2,5],[1,3],[2,5]];

var result = arr.filter(function(t) {
  var key = t.join('-');
  return this[key] ? false : (this[key] = true);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: So basically the object is created as an argument?

Comment: Nope. The Object is created as the `this` passed to the object by [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The current tuple (the sub array) is passed as an argument to the callback.

Comment: I think "hash" should be renamed "key" or similar and could just be `key = t.join('-')`.